# Retrieve news feed using facebook API

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-fql

Hi I have been looking for hours but cannot find the API call that retrieves a user's news feed (i.e the thing that you see at http://www.facebook.com/home.php). I think this should be something extremely easy. What did I miss?
I would prefer an answer with FQL, but other API methods will be just fine, as I think I can translate between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! The way is to look in the stream for post from users that are your friends. This is kind of annoying because it takes double the effort just to do some very basic task. In Objective-C using [FBConnect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect) the code look like this:

```
NSString *connections = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select target_id from connection where source_id == %lld", _uid];
NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select message from stream where source_id in (%@)", connections];
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
```

Comment: do you get the same data that appears in http://www.facebook.com/home.php ? can you build the same page if you wish to?

Comment: yes you will get the same set of data, and yes of course you can :D if you can do ajax :D

Comment: may i ask you to elaborate this one .im not fond of Objective-C :)

Comment: @kapitanluffy I think this one is quite outdated. I stopped doing iPhone so I can't help much, you will have better luck searching the docs :)

Answer (score 2):

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home

Note: /me/home retrieves an outdated view of the News Feed. This is currently a known issue and we (Facebook) don't have any near term plans to bring them back up into parity.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

the first example is how to properly get the news feed.